# Get all street addresses using zipcode/portal code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

How do I get all street addresses using a postal code. If google map api is capable of this, I would love to try it. But Im open to any api that provide those information.

So basically, I need to get a list of street addresses when only data I have is a zipcode.

Comment: That is an insane amount of data. The google map API currently will only return the middle of that postal code. It can do what is nearby with a maximum of 50,000meters

Comment: @TahTatsumoto Thanks dude for the response. Will yea- it's gonna be a lot of data because basically google map API will return other stuff I don't need. That's why I was looking for other alternative that will only return Array of street addresses within the given zip. Otherwise I have to deal with google map API- provided they can give what I need. I think I will just have to filter those results.